# How to prevent user from editing the file name of a infopath form inside the library of a Sharepoint site

Tags: document-library, infopath

Suppose I have a Sharepoint site that have a Library full of InfoPath forms. I don't want anyone (regardless if the user is the owner of the InfoPath form or whoever) to edit the filename of any of the InfoPath forms. Is it possible and how do one goes about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Like any other SharePoint list or Library, InfoPath form library also inherits permission from the parent web site. You can remove that inheritance and remove other permission to suit your needs. But make sure that, users are able to submit the forms into the library with the minimum permission that you have given.

**Option 2**

Add the SharePoint library as a web part into another page, so that all users can only access the forms from this page. In this case, the default view for this web part should only have the column Name(linked to document) and not the column Name(linked to document with edit menu). This will block users from editing the properties of the InfoPath form.

Answer (score 0):

You can set different rules before submitting form. Refer this..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37093/Submitting-an-InfoPath-Form-to-SharePoint-with-a-U